# Lexical and syntax analyzers

Tags: bison, flex-lexer

I'm new at writing flex and bison programs. I was trying to make a simple lexical and syntax analyzers. when I tried to compile them I had a list of errors.
How should I declare identifiers ?

```
Lexical.l.10: error: 'idf' undeclared <first use in this fucntion>
Lexical.l.11: error: 'cst' undeclared <first use in this fucntion>
Lexical.l.12: error: 'aff' undeclared <first use in this fucntion>
Lexical.l.13: error: 'pvg' undeclared <first use in this fucntion>
Lexical.l.15: error: syntax error before '}' token
```

and here is my program :

```
%{
#include"Syntax.tab.h"
int nb = 1;
%}
lettre [a-zA-Z]
chiffre [0-9]
IDF {lettre}({lettre}|{chiffre})*
cst {chiffre}+
%%
{IDF} return idf;
{cst} return cst;
= return aff;
; return pvg;
[ \t]
\n {nb++}
. printf("erreur lexicale a la ligne %d \n",nb);

%%
main()
    {
    yylex();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post links to images, copy the error text into the question. Links can go down over time and they make it difficult for answerers to copy and paste your code.

Comment: @ggorlen thank you ! now I've copied the error text and the program. thanks for helping me

Comment: Normally the token identifiers are generated automatically by bison and placed into the header file it generates. You seem to be including the bison-generated header file: are you not declaring the tokens in your Syntax.y file?

Comment: @rici I declared the tokens in Syntax.y file : 



    %token idf cst aff pvg
    %%
    S:idf aff cst pvg {printf("syntaxe correcte");YYACCEPT;};
    
    %%
    main()
    {
    yyparse();
    }
    yywrap();
    {}

Comment: Good. Did you run bison after you last edited the Syntax.y file? It's not automatic; if you don't regenerate the header file, your scanner will have the wrong (or missing) token declarations. (I strongly recommend using `make` to build your project because it is very easy to accidentally leave out a build step or do them in the wrong order, leading to all sorts of obscure bugs and errors.)

Answer (score 3):

If you have defined all your tokens correctly in your `Syntax.y` file, then the most likely thing is that either you did not rerun bison after your last edit to `Syntax.y`, or that you failed to specify the correct header filename when you ran bison. In either case, the `#include` statement in your scanner will be picking up an outdated version in which the token identifiers had different names or didn't exist.

The last error message:

```
Lexical.l.15: error: syntax error before '}' token
```

is correctly indicating that you left out a semicolon here:

```
\n {nb++}
```

It should be

```
\n { nb++; }
```

Also, flex requires rules to have actions, so this is not correct:

```
[ \n]
```

It should be

```
[ \t]     ; /* Ignore spaces and tabs */
```

(The semicolon is required to indicate that the action is to do nothing. The comment is just there to make nothing more visible.)

Comment: It was indeed as you said, my scanner was picking up an  outdated version. thank you for your help